# Opening excel file locked by OneDrive

Tags: c#, excel, file, onedrive, file-access

I need to read from an excel file while it is open in excel, and the file is stored in a synced OneDrive folder.

The following works flawlessly when the file is open in excel and OneDrive syncing is paused, or the file is in a non OneDrive folder:

`var fileStream = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)`

However, when the file is in OneDrive and OneDrive is syncing, I get the following exception:

`System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\xxxx' because it is being used by another process.`

This exception would be expected if a stricter FileShare, FileAccess or FileMode was used, but in this case it seems that it is actually OneDrive that locks the file in a specific way.

Does anybody have experience with and/or a solution to this?

Comment: You have to give us more informations.
Probably you opened that file somewhere, and forgot to close it.
Do you have any C# code?

Comment: The file is supposed to be open. Edited question for clarity.

Comment: He says the file IS open, that's part of the case. Normally you can read files open in Excel (or other programs) when specifying FileShare.ReadWrite, but in this case it seems Onedrive is putting some kind of extra lock on the file. DISCLAIMER: I am a colleague of OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy that file to new location and open it from there.

```
var sourceFile = new FileInfo("C:\Users\xxxx");
sourceFile.CopyTo("C:\Users\AnotherLocationNotBeingSyncedWIthOneDrive\xxxx2", true);
```